# Virtual Hosts in CentOS 7 + Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, centos7, virtual-hosts

I have problems with my VirtualHosts

The Directory of the website is /var/www/html/laravel
The httpd.conf file is

[image]

When open the website show me this error:
[image]

Somebody can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Your servername should not include the /laravel part. That's the only problem.

Comment: Also change dark blue to cyan or something!

Comment: @Farkie  but i have 2 websites in /var/www/html. I removed the /laravel for a test, but not working too.

Comment: Sure, they need to have different hostnames then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a Solution!

I have many sites in /var/www/html folder.
www.example.com/site1
www.example.com/site2
...

The solution is create one alias for each site in **httpd.conf**.
example:

```
Alias /site1 /var/www/html/site1
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site1"
</VirtualHost>

Alias /laravel /var/www/html/laravel/public
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/public

       <Directory /var/www/html/laravel>
              AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```