# Laravel on Nginx 404

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, lemp

I have two sites in my centos 7 VPS. One is laravel 5.6 (let say, def.com) and the other is static html site (let say, abc.com).

The html site is running smoothly with this config:
    `sites-available/abc.com.conf`

```
    server {
        listen   80;
        server_name  server_name abc.com www.abc.com;

        # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
        #root   /var/www/abc.com/html;
        #index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/abc.com/html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

But when I am adjust the config for laravel project, like below, it come with 404

`sites-available/def.com.conf`

```
    server {
        listen   80;
        server_name  server_name def.com www.def.com;

        # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
        #root   /var/www/def.com/public;
        #index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/def.com/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

I am using this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-on-centos-7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594407/virtual-hosts-in-centos-7-laravel

Comment: i am not running on a virtual host @AbdullaNilam

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this problem is in any way related to [tag:lemp]?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

replace this

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

with

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

after that run

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Worked Like Charm. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the root and index directives in the server block (outside of the location block), and modify the try files to: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`

Also you have the server_name two times on the 3rd line.

You can find a comprehensive guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I did what you say but it doesn't work.
Anyway, I've 2 server_name because of i want to declare with and without www, and it's running smooth with static site.

Comment: I understand that you want it to work with and without www, but I meant you literally wrote twice "server_name  server_name"
Have you uploaded the laravel app to the server and configured it properly?

Comment: I've tried one server_name and it didn't work. Yes, I've uploaded laravel app to server and configured it properly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for my method.

In my case, it was due to insufficient rights. I fixed it as follows.

```
 chown -R www-data domain_folder.uz
```